# Azure Mobile Services and TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, azure, visual-studio-2013, typescript, azure-mobile-services

How to use TypeScript for Mobile Services scripts (with node.js backend)?

Is there a definition file for Mobile Services? (on the server, not on the client!)

And how about the tooling?
Sure, I can open the scripts in Visual Studio 2013 via the Azure node in the Server Explorer, but than they are not part of a Visual Studio solution. How to add a definition file via NuGet in that case?

Answer (score 1):

If you enable source control on your mobile service, you can upload your scripts via git. This would enable a workflow where you write your scripts in TS, run the compiler to output JS, and you commit the generated js files to your repository and push them to the server.

Unfortunately I do not have any advice regarding tooling support.

Comment: Is there a typescript definition file for Mobile Services?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TypeScript definition here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/azure-mobile-services-client.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped